# SolrJ: SolrQuery.setFields method for dynamic field

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a SOLR schema with 50+ fields and 5 of them are dynamic fields.
One of the dynamic fields is "skuForSize_*" and I need to retrieve this dynamic field along with other static fields.
I am using *setFields()* method of **SolrQuery** class. It works fine with static fields but could not fetch dynamic fields. Is there any other way to fetch dynamic fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skuForSize_*` mask any field that matches your prefix. In example you could save a document with a field `skuForSize_myField1` that is not present in the `schema.xml` and it will work.
For query you need to explicitly enumerate the fields `skuForSize_field1,skuForSize_field2` ... or just use a `copy field` in ex: `textSkuForSize` and search on it.

Comment: copy field would definitely help me in this case. Thanks a lot.